# Show an element at the bottom of the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, layout

In a guestbook I have a button at the bottom of the page which displays  the input form on click:

```
$("a#showform").click(function(){ 
  $(this).hide();
  $("div#post").show("slow");
});
```

The problem is that the appearing form is outside the current view port and only manual scrolling makes the form visible to the user. I couldn't find any solution from the web but this must be a very common issue. Isn't there a jquery command to "stick to bottom" or similar?

Next thing is: I use [nanoScroller](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/) on the whole page, so normal downscrolling methods won't work here. nanoScroller has a method scroll:"bottom" but it isn't smooth...

Thank you very much,
Toni

Comment: would be nice to see a jsfiddle.

Comment: Toni, any acceptable answer so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easially scroll to the bottom of the page whenever your webpage expands :

```
 $("a#showform").click(function(){ 
        $(this).hide();
        $("div#post").show("slow");
        $('html, body').animate({
                                     scrollTop:$(document).height()
                                }, 'slow');
    });
```

you can set the 'slow' of the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to any speed in miliseconds.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKA/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just ajust the scrolling within your function

```
$("a#showform").click(function(){ 
  $(this).hide();
  $("div#post").show("slow");
  /* $(scroll magically to #post) */
  $("div#post").nanoScroller({ scroll: 'top' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use css to solve this problem if you aren't concerned with the post item covering other elements:

```
div#post {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```